# Cast a numeric string value to an integer?

Tags: apex

How do I cast the value digit in the substring to an integer?

```
integer check2 = nif.substring(1,1) * 8;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast `String` to `Integer` as `String` is never an instance of `Integer`

In general to cast one type to another, cover object that should be cast to another type with brackets

```
Object check2 = ((Object)nif.substring(1,1));
```

---

I recommend you to use `Integer.valueOf` method

> Returns an Integer that contains the value of the specified String. As
>   in Java, the String is interpreted as representing a signed decimal
>   integer.

```
Integer check2 = Integer.valueOf(nif.substring(1,1)) * 8;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer check2 = Integer.valueOf(nif.substring(1,1)) * 8;
```